# Changing the wording in a PNG image

Tags: logo, png

I have two PNG images, which make up the logo for a show I have. The name of the show changed. How do I change the lettering in the PNG. I lost touch with the original designer. Thanks! [image]

Comment: PNGs don't have editable text. They're just made of pixels. You'd basically need to recreate it from scratch, i.e. type it again, using the same font, and apply the emboss, outline, and drop shadow effects.

Answer (score 1):

PNG files are raster images. Merely a collection of pixels. What the PNG displays, via its pixels, can be anything from a person's portrait to a block of text. Nonetheless, it's *all* still merely pixels.

In order to edit *pixels* you need to paint or draw, you *can not* use any type tools. Type, in a PNG is **not** "live" or directly editable. Think of it like a poster hanging on a wall... it may have text on it.... but in order to change that text you would need to paint over the exiting text then create new text on top of the paint over. That is what has to be done to edit type in a PNG file.

There is no simply, easy, quick, method to alter type in a png.

---

All that being posted, what you have is merely text on a transparent background. All you really need do is create new type and try and work out the layer styles used originally.

[image]

<sub>(Font's not the same, I know.)</sub>

Just playing around for a bit, this is close but not exact.....

[image]

[image][image]

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: There's one little add-on to your answer: Macromedia Fireworks (later Adobe) used the same file extension for its source files. So PNGs created in Fireworks were actually editable. https://superuser.com/questions/50044/how-to-read-fireworks-png-multilayer-files-without-fireworks

Comment: @Luciano Well, yes. But That was entirely proprietary to Fireworks if the PNG was created in Fireworks. And since Fireworks has been dead for nearly 10 years now and it won't actually run on any current operating system, I didn't feel the need to mention it.

Comment: I get it. Is it 10 years already? I'm getting old...

Comment: Thanks! You've saved me from trying to do the impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

If you knew what the font was, that would be helpful in recreating it (just need to add those coloring effects).

If you could get the original source file that would make things much easier.